# Replacing a nested dictionary into empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following `nested_dict`:

```
{'view_0': {'spain': -1}, 'view_1': {'portugal': 0}, 'view_2': {'morocco': 1.0, 'france': -1.0}, 'view_3': {'germany': 0.5, 'italy': 0.5, 'uk': -0.5, 'ireland': -0.5}}
```

On the other side, I have the following `empty_df`, wherein the index appears the keys of the `nested_dict`. and in the columns the `key` found in the values of each `nested_dict`.

```
            spain  portugal  morocco  france  germany  italy  uk   ireland
view_0          0    0         0        0       0       0      0      0             
view_1          0    0         0        0       0       0      0      0       
view_2          0    0         0        0       0       0      0      0       
view_3          0    0         0        0       0       0      0      0
```

I would like to place the `values.values()` of `nested_dict` in the `empty_df` to obtain the following output:

```
            spain  portugal  morocco  france  germany  italy  uk   ireland
view_0         -1    0         0        0       0       0      0      0             
view_1          0    0         0        0       0       0      0      0       
view_2          0    0         1       -1       0       0      0      0       
view_3          0    0         0        0      0.5     0.5   -0.5   -0.5
```

And in order to do so I tried a

```
empty_df.replace(nested_dict)
```

However returns the `empty_dict` filled with zeros, not substituting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and replace empty values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(0)
```

Also is possible add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same columns and index names in same ordering like `empty_df`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
                  .reindex(columns=empty_df.columns, index=df_empty.index)
                  .fillna(0))
```

---

```
print (df)
        spain  portugal  morocco  france  germany  italy   uk  ireland
view_0   -1.0       0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0
view_1    0.0       0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0
view_2    0.0       0.0      1.0    -1.0      0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0
view_3    0.0       0.0      0.0     0.0      0.5    0.5 -0.5     -0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct a dataframe from your dictionary and use [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

df.update(df_data)

print(df)

        spain  portugal  morocco  france  germany  italy   uk  ireland
view_0   -1.0       0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0
view_1    0.0       0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0
view_2    0.0       0.0      1.0    -1.0      0.0    0.0  0.0      0.0
view_3    0.0       0.0      0.0     0.0      0.5    0.5 -0.5     -0.5
```